# How to access a valid OCaml identifier from Reason that is a reserved keyword in Reason

Tags: ocaml, reserved-words, reason

Is there a way to use an OCaml identifier that is a reserved keyword in Reason?

Let's consider the following example:

```ml
(* some_library.ml (valid OCaml) *)
type pub = {
  x: string;
}
```

When I try to use the type `pub` from Reason,

```
/* MyApp.re (invalid ReasonML) */
type someTypeAlias = Some_library.pub;
```

a syntax error error is displayed because "pub" is a reserved keyword in Reason.

```
Error: 743: pub is a reserved keyword, it cannot be used as an identifier. Try `pub_` or `_pub` instead
```

If I try to use the suggested identifiers (`_pub` or `pub_`), it doesn't work, because these expect the same name in the OCaml file.

To be more specific, I'm trying to use [`pub` type in Nocrypto library](https://github.com/mirleft/ocaml-nocrypto/blob/a58c6534c5cc5da1598f8c979ea397ea2c6b92e1/src/nocrypto.mli#L840).

*It would be nice if there was a way to escape a keyword in ReasonML or specify accessed name in OCaml... Something like*

```
/* MyApp.re (draft/invalid ReasonML) */
type someTypeAlias = Some_library.[@reason.keyword_as_identifier "pub"];
```

Is there something like that? Or wouldn't it be possible to create some workaround using `external`? I'm not very excited about forking the library just to rename one type.

Comment: I think this is a bug in the current release (3.4.0) of Reason.  Value names are translated but type names don't appear to be.  Until that's fixed, @octachron's answer is a reasonable workaround.

Comment: Issue created here: https://github.com/facebook/reason/issues/2341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to add a type alias in an Ocaml-syntax wrapper:

```
 type notpub = pub = { x: string }
```